# Why is there no letter-spacing between a nested inline element and a following character?

Tags: html, css

After reading the spec for letter-spacing, I understand that runs of atomic inlines (e.x. inline-block) elements are treated as a single character (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#letter-spacing):

> For the purpose of letter-spacing, each consecutive run of atomic inlines (such as image and/or inline blocks) is treated as a single character.

In all browsers I tested (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE 9+10), it doesn't seem to work like this.

The following code (http://codepen.io/caleb/pen/CqDfK):

```
<style>
    div { letter-spacing: 2em; }
    em { letter-spacing: normal; }
</style>
<div>
    a<em>em</em><em>em</em>bc
</div>
```

is rendered like:

```
a    ememb    c
```

Is there a reason why there isn't an additional 2em of spacing between the `emem` and the `b`? Since the `emem` is a single character.

Comment: I tested the above code in IE7, and it gives me: `aememb  c`, and in IE8 it is the same as in the original post. It sounds like nobody has moved to implement this part of the spec yet.

Comment: CSS2.1 does not say much about [`letter-spacing`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#spacing-props), but it does say that [non-replaced inline elements are *not* atomic inlines](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-boxes). This means elements such as `em`, which are `display: inline` by default, are *not* atomic inlines. That said, declaring `display: inline-block` in your `em` rule makes no difference in current browsers regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the spec does not seem to be fully implemented as you comment, but I am not sure. When I put in a modified version of the example from [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#letter-spacing) (modified in that I made all inner elements `em` and changed sizes to see better; changes in quote below given in brackets)...

> For example, given the markup
>
> ```
> <P>a<LS>b<Z>cd</Z><Y>ef</Y></LS>g</P>
> ```
>
> and the style sheet
>
> ```
> LS [em] { letter-spacing: 1em; } 
>
> Z [em > em] { letter-spacing: 0.3em; [made 3em in example] }
>
> Y [em > em + em] { letter-spacing: 0.4em; [made 6em in example]}
> ```
>
> the spacing would be
>
> ```
> a[0]b[1em]c[0.3em]d[1em]e[0.4em]f[0]g
> ```

...it [does not render according to what they state](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hEgHc), which implies some variation to the spec. Instead, the rule that *appears* to be followed is that the *preceding* letter's `letter-spacing` value determines the space that follows it. This might be an implementation based on the interpretation of this statement from the spec:

> At element boundaries, the total letter spacing between two characters
>   is given by and rendered within the innermost element that *contains*
>   the boundary.

But I am not sure of that. At any rate, following what *appears* to be the rule the browser's are using, that the *preceding* letter's `letter-spacing` value determines the spacing, then ***that explains the answer to your question*** of

> Is there a reason why there isn't an additional 2em of spacing between
>   the emem and the b?

It is because the letter preceding the `b` is the `m` contained in a `letter-spacing: normal` coded element, which gives a zero width spacing *after* it. I don't believe the reference...

> For the purpose of letter-spacing, each consecutive run of atomic
>   inlines (such as image and/or inline blocks) is treated as a single
>   character

...has much to do with it. That just indicates that such "atomic inlines" function as a unit, and an `em` is not an atomic inline by default ([see second paragraph of 9.2.2 in this spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes)). So in [this example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gqalm), the `width` of the `inline-block` element determines where the `g` is placed, not the fact that the `f` happens to now be *after* the `g`, because the whole block is functioning as an atomic unit.

Comment: I think you are right. In my original post I wanted to talk about inline-block elements, which made the as-a-single-character rule apply, but I thought that it would needlessly complicate the question.

Comment: So, the consensus is that the browsers are deviating from the spec, since the spec provides the desired rendering of the LS,Z,Y example, which browsers do not follow, right?

Comment: @CalebLand: I would say that since the application of the spacing does not turn out as the example, that there seems to be something in the spec that is not being followed by the browsers. But admittedly, the spec is a bit vague to me, so I can somewhat see why that is the case.